# Yii update cgridview via button not working in IFRAME

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

Im trying to update CGridview after update of mongodb via button in Cjuidiag box.
MY Code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
'id'=>'uploaddialog',
'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Edit Documents',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
    'width'=>958,
    'height'=>623,
),
));
?>
<iframe id="cru-frame-struct" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" scrolling="yes" > 
<?php //$this->renderPartial('uploaddocument',array()); ?>
</iframe>

<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'Prd-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
       array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn','template' => '{updateline}',                              
            'buttons' => array( 
            'updateline' => array(
            'options'=>array('style'=>'margin-left:20px'),
            'imageUrl'=>\Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png',
            'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("editdocument", 
            array("id"=>$data["Document_id"],"OriginObject"=>isset($data["OriginObject"])?$data["OriginObject"]:""))',        //                                          
            'click'=>'function(){ 
                     $("#cru-frame-struct").attr("src",$(this).attr("href"));                                                                                                            
                     $("#uploaddialog").dialog("open");  
                       return false;
                     }',
                 )  
            ),
    ),
        array(
        'name' => 'ID',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data["Document_id"]'
    ),          
    ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => ""
),

));

?>
```

**Uploaddocument.php**

```
<?php echo CHtml::button('Update WorkFlow',array('id'=>'updworkflow','class'=>'btn','onclick'=>'workflow()','background-style'=>'none')); ?>                
 <h4><?php echo "Document Log";?></h4>
   <?php 


    $mongo = new MongoClient( Yii::app()->mongodb->connectionString);  
    $dbname = Yii::app()->mongodb->dbName;  
    $temp = array();
    $colname = 'Documents';   
    $collection = $mongo->$dbname->$colname;   
    $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id" => new MongoId($DocId)));
    foreach ($dcursor as $ddoc) {
    if(isset($ddoc['Workflows']))
    {
        $sdoc =($ddoc['Workflows']);        
        foreach ($sdoc as $wflw) 
        {           
            $temp ["Date"]= $wflw["Date"];
            $temp ["Initials"]= $wflw["Initials"];
            $temp ["Status"]= $wflw["Status"];
            $temp ["Comments"]= $wflw["Comments"];
            $pendarray[] = $temp;
        }
    }
    }
    $dataProvider = new \CArrayDataProvider ($pendarray,array('keyField'=>'Date')); 

     $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'documentlog-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'columns' => array(             
            array(
            'name' => 'Date',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'isset($data["Date"])?$data["Date"]:""'
        ),
            array(
            'name' => 'Initials',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'isset($data["Initials"])?$data["Initials"]:""'
        ),  
            array(
            'name' => 'Status',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'isset($data["Status"])?$data["Status"]:""'
        ),              
            array(
            'name' => 'Comment',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'isset($data["Comments"])?$data["Comments"]:""'
        ),
        ),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
        'class' => ""
        ),  
    )); 
   ?>
```

**Controller.php:**

```
public function actionUpdateWorkflow()
{
    $status = isset($_POST["Status"])?$_POST["Status"]:"";
    $comments = isset($_POST["Comments"])?$_POST["Comments"]:"";
    $now = new \DateTime(); 
    $mongo = new \MongoClient( \Yii::app()->mongodb->connectionString);  
    $dbname = \Yii::app()->mongodb->dbName; 
    $colname = 'Documents';
    $mongo->$dbname->$colname->update(array("_id" => new \MongoId($_POST["id"])),
                    array('$addToSet' =>  array(
                        'Workflows' => array(
                        'Date' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                        'Initials' =>\Yii::app()->user->getUserName(),
                        'Status'=>$status,
                        'Comments'=>$comments,
                        )))
                    );      

   //echo \CHtml::script("$.fn.yiiGridView.update('documentlog-grid'); 
         //  window.parent.$.fn.yiiGridView.update('documentlog-grid');");                              
        \Yii::app()->end();
}
public function actionIndex()
{   
    $this->render('index');
}

public function actioneditdocument()
{
        $this->layout = '//layouts/customIFrame';   

            $this->renderPartial('uploaddocument',array(
                        'DocId'=>$DocId,
                    ));         
        }           

}
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function workflow()
{   
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url :"<?php echo CController::createUrl('default/UpdateWorkflow'); ?>",
        data:{"Comments":comments,
              "Status":status,
              "id":docid        
             }, 
        success:function (data) {
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('documentlog-grid');       
              return true;
        }
        error: function(){
                  alert('failure ');
                  }
    });
}
</script>
```

Im not sure what mistake in this code. i'm populating grid with mongo Data. i want to refresh grid data after every update/insert in mongodb by button.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I make this documentlog-grid as separate IFRAME in success  var iframe = document.getElementById('cru-frame-resgrid');
iframe.contentWindow.document.write(data);
iframe.contentWindow.document.close();

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like that and tell me how it is working:

`$('#documentlog-grid').yiiGridView('update');`

Also try it from the browser console.

Comment: I'm passing the variable and updating works fine, my issue is not refreshing the grid

Comment: Does the grid update happens if you hit `F5` after pressing the button and waiting for the Ajax post to finish?

Comment: in your ajax call you try to set `complete: function (data) {
                $.fn.yiiGridView.update('documentlog-grid');       
             }` to run update in any case (even if not successed).

Comment: @Selvi, you said you "populating grid with mongo Data". How do you form $dataProvider? Could you expose the code?